# String.Split with specific tags

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a string of html tags. for example ive got a string :

```
<p></p>

<table>

<table><p></p></table>


</table>
```

what i want to retrive is :

```
<table>

<table><p></p></table>


</table>
```

the problem is right now that when i am calling :

```
string[] values = pContent.Split(new string[] {"<table>","</table>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

im getting :

```
<table>

    <table><p></p>
```

How do i get the rest?

Comment: Try http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ instead

Comment: Split isn't going to do this, even regex is going to be painful. xml / html parser is the way to go.

Comment: is it possible to use html parser in xslt file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
        string input = String.Concat("<root>", @"<p></p><table><table><p></p></table></table>", "</root>");

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
        var valuesStr = doc.Root.Element("table").ToString();
        string[] values = Regex.Matches(valuesStr, @"<.+?>")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(o => o.Groups[0].Value)
            .ToArray();
```

It first creates an instance of XDocument class (one of the classes for parsing XML), it adds root element named "root" just to be able to create XDocument (every XML document must have a root). XML document's content is parsed from string. Then it gets the string containing textual representation of a document - to do that first the Root property is accessed because "table" element is just below the root node, after that Element() method with "table" is invoked which gets the first element with name "table" under the root (in this example there is only one such element below the node), after that ToString() gets the textual description.

Regex.Matches is used to extract every single element from the string, it returns MatchCollection which is then cast to IEnumerable by Cast(), after that Select() extension method is called on IEnumerable which gets the textual values captured by Regex.Matches for every Match in IEnumerable, then these values are returned as string[] by ToArray() method.

Comment: and we got a winner. Can u explain what u did?

Comment: Sure, I read the question one more time, and thought to replace the answer with `string[] values = doc.Root.Descendants("table").Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();` which would return all elements named "table", but it's OK if that's the desired result. I'll add explanations to the answer.

Comment: thatnks alot for exaplnation, never used XDocument before